# How to disable screen reader in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, screen-readers

I am using the most recent version of Chrome on Elementary OS / Linux.

This only appears on some sites and I've asked others to check for me and it appears to be just me. It "scans" the sites for interactive elements, if I select a dropdown it shows the screen in the ss.

I looked at my Chrome settings and I don't have any readers on and I don't have any extensions that are readers. I am at a loss..

[image]

Comment: What makes you think it's a screen reader issue? I didn't see anything in your question or in the screen shot that indicates it's related to screen readers.  And what is the "It" in *"It \*scans\* the sites for interactive elements"*?  And what dropdown are you referring to? There's a dropdown on the page you happened to be viewing?  And by dropdown, do you mean a `<select>/<option>` element are do you mean a submenu?

Comment: @slugolicious it literally says "Playing to screen readers" in the bottom left hand corner...

Comment: Sorry, the screenshot text was so small that I didn’t see that. In general, browsers have no idea that a screen reader is running so I’m surprised to see that message. Do you have a production/public version of the website that I can try?